# Is it possible to insert a menu item at a specific position in Dijit using Dijit/Menu

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, dojo

I have a menu whose contents need to change significantly based on user interaction. This means that some new menu items need to be introduced, and some need to be removed. Looking at Dojo's published API documentation, there doesn't seem to be a way to redo a menu's contents without removing existing items and recreating the menu from scratch.

`dijit/Menu`'s `getChildren()` method returns an array suggesting that there might be a relatively simple way of inserting menu options at specific index positions. Unfortunately, however, I can't find a way to attach an array of menu items into a `dijit/Menu`.

Does anyone know of a direct way (using the API)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer suggested by @gabriel was my starting point, and I noticed that it's possible to add menu items at a specific position by specifying the index in [Menu.addChild](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_Menu_addChild).

> `addChild(widget,insertIndex)`

What I ended up doing eventually was something different:

- Loop through `menu.getChildren()` to the index that I was looking for
- Remove the menu item (using `removeChild`)
- Add new menu item (using `addChild`)

I couldn't use `insertIndex` since my menu had separators that needed to be handled (sigh!).

Answer (score 1):

`dijit/Menu` is missing some fairly mainline use-cases. I made a custom implementation that added the various features I always seemed to want. Among them is toggling a given menu item.

[I've pastebin'd my "`dijit/ContextMenu`" widget (my name, not theirs) here](http://pastebin.com/zWRzT8pr), but the answer is no, you have to do it yourself. You can either dynamically add/remove `MenuItem`s as needed, or what I do is inject them all at creation-time, then show/hide as needed:

```
    [snip]
    hideMenuItem :function(menuItemId){
        var menuItems = this.getChildren();
        for(var i=0; i < menuItems.length; ++i){
            if(menuItemId === menuItems[i].id){
                domStyle.set(menuItems[i].domNode, "display", "none");
                break;
            }
        }
    },

    showMenuItem : function(menuItemId){
        var menuItems = this.getChildren();
        for(var i=0; i < menuItems.length; ++i){
            if(menuItemId === menuItems[i].id){
                domStyle.set(menuItems[i].domNode, "display", "");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    [/snip]
```

Comment: Thanks @gabriel, I ended up doing something else as what I wanted to do was not showing and hiding so much as adding and removing items depending on the context of my app.

With that said, I did notice that it's possible to add menu items at a specific position by specifying the index in Menu.addChild (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_Menu_addChild)

Comment: How about that! Try to help and get helped instead. Hah. I have updated my pastebin with the insertIndex, maybe it'll help someone else one day. I suggest you answer your own question though, since you solved the issue.